# CSS priority in nested tables

Tags: html, css

I have been improving code that transforms XML to HTML. There is a recursive method that generates a table.

I want each level to have different color. So I set a style for three levels and I repeat them if the recursion is deeper (level % 3).

But it seems that parent table style gets priority as the fourth level has the same color as its parent. Can I work around this trouble?

http://jsbin.com/lexumogafe

[image: sample]

```
<html>
<head><style>
    table { border-collapse: collapse; }
    table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
    th, td { padding: 10px; }
    table.level_1 td { border-color: green; }
    table.level_2 td { border-color: blue; }
    table.level_3 td { border-color: red; }
</style></head>
<body>
    <table class='rule level_1'>
    <tr class="all">
        <td>XX</td>
        <td>
            <table class='rule level_2'>
            <tr class="all">
                <td>YY</td>
                <td>
                    <table class='rule level_3'>
                    <tr class="all">
                        <td>ZZ</td>
                        <td>
                            <table class='rule level_1'>
                            <tr class="all">
                                <td>ZZ</td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the styles specific to the actual `td`s using the direct child selector:

```
table.level_1 > tbody > tr > td { border-color: green; }
table.level_2 > tbody > tr > td { border-color: blue; }
table.level_3 > tbody > tr > td { border-color: red; }
```

[Updated bin](http://jsbin.com/qasizaluvo/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the answer in 7 minutes once it is allowed.

Answer (score -2):

use css parent child relation like

```
table > table > td
{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

this way css property will apply only to its child element not siblings.